# Pandas Python How to handle question mark that appeared in dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have these question marks that appeared in my data frame just next to numbers and I dont know how to erase or or replace them. I dont want to drop the whole row since it may result in inaccurate results.

```js
. Value
0  58
1  82
2  69
3  48
4  8
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like a white space character. Try `df.Value.str.strip()`

Comment: which encoding did you use to read your file?

Comment: @Manakin Pandas Python

Comment: `pandas` is not an enconding, I meant did you specify an encoding like `UTF-8` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments above that you should look into how you imported the data.  But here is the answer to your question of how to remove the non numeric characters:

This will remove the non numeric characters

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Then if you wish to change the datatype to in you can use this:

```
df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'])
```